# Handling very noisy images

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a bunch of very noisy images from which I would like to extract contours and postprocess the pixels within these contours. One of these images is shows below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NK81.jpg)

Because of the noise, the contours are discontinuous and difficult to detect. Is there a way to handle very noisy images? I do postprocessing in Python.

Answer (score 0):

As this noise is mostly impulsive, linear filters will perform poorly (Gaussian, bilateral). Rather try a median filter (or maybe non-local means).

Here is the result of four passes with an 11x11 mdedian:

[image]

Then the same followed by bilateral:

[image]

Don't expect a perfect delineation of the outlines as those are anyway buried in noise.

Comment: This looks quite good! Did you use cv2 for this or anything similar?

Comment: And with "four passes" you mean it is passed through the median filter four times?

Comment: @DozerD: yep, four passes, for slightly better isotropy. I used my own software, mViz.